# Origin of the symbol for the tensor product

Tags: ho.history-overview, tensor-products, notation

I have recently realised that the Paleo-Hebrew (and Phoenician) graph for the Hebrew letter ט ([Teth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teth)) is $\otimes$. This made me wonder if there is any relation between the choice of the symbol and the choice of the name (as far as I am aware, *tensor* product is meant to be a *stretched* product, coming from latin *tendere* although I confess I can't understand why the tensor product of two spaces, or modules, or elements, should be thought as being "stretched"), since ט is the letter used in modern and ancient Hebrew to denote the sound T in words borrowed from other languages.

I have checked the Archives Bourbaki, in particular the [second redaction](http://archives-bourbaki.ahp-numerique.fr/items/show/442) (n°034) of *Algèbre. Chapitre II, algèbre linéaire* and the corresponding [discussion](http://archives-bourbaki.ahp-numerique.fr/items/show/82) which seem to me the first occurrences of the name (still called "produit tensoriel (ou kroneckerien)", see *ibid.* p. 198) and of the symbol, but found no hints. The tensor product is presented as a special case of the *bilinear product* of two modules, which is denoted by $\odot$, itself not a graph that I am aware of in the Paleo-Hebrew alphabet: the circle in $\otimes$ could simply come from the one in $\odot$, but it might also be related to the first letter T of *tensor*.

Is there any reference I can look at for more information?

Comment: on the origin of the word "tensor" in mathematics see: http://jeff560.tripod.com/t.html

Comment: The symbol $\oplus$ was used in [Linear B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_B#Syllabic_signs) to write the syllable *ka-* in Mycenean Greek. Like the above, this would seem to be only a coincidence.

Comment: It should be noted that throughout history, nearly every culture that has ever been has had some kind of circle as its first symbol, some kind of cross as its second symbol, and some combination of the two as a very early development thereafter. There are easily hundreds of independent symbols that can be generally described as a an X inscribed in a circle.

Comment: @KRyan To me, my X-Men ...

Comment: @KRyan You're probably right in saying this, yet the question of whether the choice has been inspired by the fact the ט is $\otimes$ in Paleo-Hebrew remains. André Weil was Jew and fond of philology, and the legend says he was responsible for introducing $\emptyset$ from the Norwegian letter Ø (a circle with a line, even more basic than a circle with a cross...): at the time of _Algèbre II_ he was still very much in contact with the Bourbaki group.

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo Oh certainly, it’s a fair question.

Comment: I thought of the letter like $\otimes$ as a forerunner of Greek $\Theta$ rather than Hebrew.  I don't see where religion comes into it.

Comment: @PaulTaylor It might very well be that the symbol of $\Theta$ has some common origin with the Paleo-Hebrew symbol for $\otimes$: after all, the Greek alphabet is derived from the Phoenician, which is the same alphabet used in Paleo-Hebrew, and Theta is the same letter as Theth.  Interesting observation, thanks! That being said, you're the first bringing religion into the picture.

Answer (score 8):

According to [John Aldrich's list](http://jeff560.tripod.com/matrices.html) of "Earliest Uses of Symbols for Matrices and Vectors", the notation $\times$ for direct product (as well as the name itself) goes back to Wedderburn's 1934 [Lectures on Matrices](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/matrices.pdf) (page 74).

[image]

Some further search gave a much earlier source, Hurwitz's 1894 [Zur Invariantentheorie](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01446685)

[image]

I still have to track down the step from $\times$ to $\otimes$.
Incidentally, [On the history of the Kronecker product](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081088308817548) argues that it should more appropriately be called the Zehfuss product.

In any case, since tensor product is $\otimes$ and tensor sum is $\oplus$, it seems obvious that the $\times$ and the $+$ refer to the arithmetical operations of multiplication and addition, not to a letter.

Comment: This is not a direct product.

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm following this [terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) --- which I understand is the one in the OP: Kronecker product = matrix direct product = $\otimes$

Comment: Huh, never heard of this terminology. It does **not** correspond to the direct product of vector spaces.

Comment: But it **does** correspond to the tensor product $S \otimes T : W \otimes X \to Y \otimes Z$ of linear maps $S : W \to Y$ and $T : X  \to Z$.

Comment: It is my understanding that historically "direct product" has sometimes been used to mean what is now known as "tensor product". Many physicists still conflate the two terminologies, e.g. see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/447342/direct-product-vs-tensor-product